# Pygame Enemy not showing on screen

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, sys

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,-16,2,512)
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('THE GAME')#Window name

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('player_animations/R1.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R2.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R3.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R4.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R5.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R6.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R7.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R8.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('player_animations/L1.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L2.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L3.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L4.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L5.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L6.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L7.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L8.png'), pygame.image.load('player_animations/L9.png')]

Window_SIZE = (900,600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(Window_SIZE,0,32)

display = pygame.Surface((900,600))

player_image = pygame.image.load('player_animations/player_image.png')
player_image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))

grass_image = pygame.image.load('Map/Grassblock.png')
grass_image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))

dirt_image = pygame.image.load('Map/Dirtblock.png')

cobble_image = pygame.image.load('Map/Stoneblock.png')

TILE_SIZE = grass_image.get_width()

true_scroll = [0,0]

#ENEMIES
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    enemy_sprite = [pygame.image.load('Map/blob.png'),pygame.image.load('Map/blob.png'),pygame.image.load('Map/blob.png'),pygame.image.load('Map/blob.png'),pygame.image.load('Map/blob.png'),pygame.image.load('Map/blob.png'),pygame.image.load('Map/blob.png'),pygame.image.load('Map/blob.png'),pygame.image.load('Map/blob.png')]
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,end):
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self.x,self.end]
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3
    
    def draw(self,display):
        self.move()
        if self.walkCount + 1 <= 33:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.vel > 0:
            display.blit(self.enemy_sprite[self.walkCount//3],(self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            display.blit(self.enemy_sprite[self.walkCount//3],(self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1     

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x += self.vel  
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel *-1
                self.move_counter = 0
        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel  
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel *-1
                self.move_counter = 0           
        

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    screen.blit(display,(0,0))
    blob.draw(display)

    if walkCount + 1 >=  27:
        walkCount = 0

    if moving_left:
        screen.blit(walkLeft[walkCount // 3],(player_rect.x-scroll[0],player_rect.y-scroll[1] ))
        walkCount += 1
            
    elif moving_right:
        screen.blit(walkRight[walkCount // 3],(player_rect.x-scroll[0],player_rect.y-scroll[1] ))
        walkCount += 1  


    else:
        screen.blit(player_image,(player_rect.x-scroll[0],player_rect.y-scroll[1]))     
    


    pygame.display.update() 
    


def load_map(path):
    f = open(path + '.txt','r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    data = data.split('\n')
    game_map = []
    for row in data:
        game_map.append(list(row))
    return game_map         

game_map = load_map('Map/map')

background_objects = [[0.2,[500,200,250,3000]],[0.5,[750,30,200,4000]],[0.3,[1000,100,235,2000]],[0.5,[130,90,100,4000]],[0.6,[300,100,220,5000]]]

def collision_test(rect,tiles):
    hit_list = []
    for tile in tiles:
        if rect.colliderect(tile):
            hit_list.append(tile)
    return hit_list
    
def move(rect,movement,tiles):
    collision_types = {'top':False,'bottom':False,'right':False,'left':False}
    rect.x += movement[0]
    hit_list = collision_test(rect,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[0] > 0:
            rect.right = tile.left
            collision_types['right'] = True
        elif movement[0] < 0:
            rect.left = tile.right
            collision_types['left'] = True
    rect.y += movement[1]           
    hit_list = collision_test(rect,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[1] > 0:
            rect.bottom = tile.top
            collision_types['bottom'] = True
        elif movement[1] < 0:
            rect.top = tile.bottom
            collision_types['top'] = True   

    return rect, collision_types


moving_right = False
moving_left = False

moving_down = False

player_y_momentum = 0
air_timer = 0

player_rect = pygame.Rect(50,50,player_image.get_width(),player_image.get_height())

player_left = False
player_right = False
player_down = False 

jump_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('jump.wav')
grass_sound = [pygame.mixer.Sound('grass_0.wav'),pygame.mixer.Sound('grass_1.wav')]

pygame.mixer.music.load('music.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

blob = Enemy(0,20,50,50,7000)

walkCount = 0

vel = 5


#Game loop
while True:
    display.fill((146,244,255))

    true_scroll[0] += (player_rect.x - true_scroll[0]-450)/20
    true_scroll[1] += (player_rect.y - true_scroll[1]-364)/20
 
    scroll = true_scroll.copy()
    scroll[0] = int(scroll[0])
    scroll[1] = int(scroll[1])

    pygame.draw.rect(display,(7,80,75),pygame.Rect(0,400,900,600))
    for background_object in background_objects:
        obj_rect = pygame.Rect(background_object[1][0]-scroll[0]*background_object[0],background_object[1][1]-scroll[1]*background_object[0],background_object[1][2],background_object[1][3])
        if background_objects[0] == 0.5:
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),obj_rect)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(9,91,85),obj_rect)    


    
    tile_rects = []
    y=0
    for row in game_map:
        x=0
        for tile in row:
            if tile != '0': 
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE))
            if tile == '1':
                display.blit(dirt_image,(x*TILE_SIZE-scroll[0],y*TILE_SIZE-scroll[1]))
            if tile == '2':
                display.blit(grass_image,(x*TILE_SIZE-scroll[0],y*TILE_SIZE-scroll[1]))
            if tile == '3':
                display.blit(cobble_image,(x*TILE_SIZE-scroll[0],y*TILE_SIZE-scroll[1]))            
            


            x += 1
        y += 1
    
    
    
    
    player_movement = [0,0]
    if moving_right:
        player_movement[0] += vel
    if moving_left:
        player_movement[0] -= vel
    #________________________________________
    if moving_down:
        player_movement[1] += 7

    #________________________________________       
    player_movement[1] += player_y_momentum 
    player_y_momentum += 0.2
    if player_y_momentum > 3:   
        player_y_momentum = 3
      

    player_rect,collisions = move(player_rect,player_movement,tile_rects)           

    if collisions['bottom']:
        player_y_momentum = 0
        air_timer = 0
    else:
        air_timer += 1


    if collisions['top']:
        player_y_momentum = 0
        air_timer = 0
    else:
        air_timer += 0.1


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
                player_right = True
                player_left = False
                player_down = False

            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
                player_left = True
                player_right = False
                player_down = False

            #_________________________
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                moving_down = True
                player_down = True
                player_left = False
                player_right = False


            
            else:
                player_right = False
                player_left = False
                player_down = False
                walkCount = 0   

            if event.key == K_UP:
                if air_timer < 6:
                    player_y_momentum = -7.5
                    player_right = False
                    player_left = False
                    player_down = False
                    walkCount = 0
                    jump_sound.play()
                    jump_sound.set_volume(0.1)



        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = False
                
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = False 

            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moving_down = False
            
        
    
                
    
    redrawGameWindow()  

    surf = pygame.transform.scale(display,Window_SIZE)
    clock.tick(54)
```

I am not getting any error or anything but my enemy_sprite is just not showing up in the Game.
Is it due to the parallax or the class has some error or something else.
The game map is based on tile rects , so i tried the tile rects to blit my enemy on the screen then it was showing on the screen but not moving at all . Pls Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw the enemy (`blob`) on the `screen` instead of the map (`display`) *Surface*

<s>`blob.draw(display)`</s>

```py
blob.draw(screen)
```